# Image save in specific folder and return that image path in PHP

Tags: php

I am trying to generate a barcode and save into one folder, and after save I want path of that image. Here is the code:

```
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
  imagejpeg($im); 
    echo  $save = "temp/". strtolower($code) .".jpeg";   
    // $save1 = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/sigs/" . strtolower($name) . ".png";
$tt= imagejpeg($im, $save);
  imagedestroy($im);
```

The image saves successfully, but path does not return or even print - what might be wrong?

Comment: echo $save = "temp/". strtolower($code) .".jpeg";  ? It saved that the "temp/". strtolower($code) .".jpeg";   is whether assigned to $save or not

Comment: header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
  imagejpeg($im); 
    echo  $save = "temp/". strtolower($code) .".jpeg";   
    // $save1 = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/sigs/" . strtolower($name) . ".png";
$tt= imagejpeg($im, $save);
  imagedestroy($im);

Comment: its save in folder properly but not print path

Comment: this question's about clear as mud.

Comment: @user2823525 Could you share your code that you have so far ?

Comment: if(isset($_POST['mySubmit'])){ 
 $code = $_POST['code']; 
 
  $fontSize = 10;   
  $marge    = 10; 
  $x        = 150;  
  $y        = 150; 
  $height   = 40;   
  $width    = 10;   
  $angle    = 90;   
 
  $type     = 'datamatrix';

  function drawCross($im, $color, $x, $y){
    imageline($im, $x - 10, $y, $x + 10, $y, $color);
    imageline($im, $x, $y- 10, $x, $y + 10, $color);
  }

Comment: $im     = imagecreatetruecolor(300, 300);
  $black  = ImageColorAllocate($im,0x00,0x00,0x00);
  $white  = ImageColorAllocate($im,0xff,0xff,0xff);
  $red    = ImageColorAllocate($im,0xff,0x00,0x00);
  $blue   = ImageColorAllocate($im,0x00,0x00,0xff);
  imagefilledrectangle($im, 0, 0, 300, 300, $white);
  
  
  $data = Barcode::gd($im, $black, $x, $y, $angle, $type, array('code'=>$code), $width, $height);

Comment: if ( isset($font) ){
    $box = imagettfbbox($fontSize, 0, $font, $data['hri']);
    $len = $box[2] - $box[0];
    Barcode::rotate(-$len / 2, ($data['height'] / 2) + $fontSize + $marge, $angle, $xt, $yt);
    imagettftext($im, $fontSize, $angle, $x + $xt, $y + $yt, $blue, $font, $data['hri']);
  }
  
  imageline($im, $x, 0, $x, 250, $red);
  imageline($im, 0, $y, 250, $y, $red);
  
  
  for($i=1; $i<5; $i++){
    drawCross($im, $blue, $data['p'.$i]['x'], $data['p'.$i]['y']);
  }

Comment: header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
 imagejpeg($im);
 $save = "temp/". strtolower($code) .".jpeg";
 echo '$save';
 
imagejpeg($im, $save);
   imagedestroy($im);
 

}

Comment: Above 4 comment contain code please merge into one file and check please

Answer (score 0):

> but path not return or even not print please help me

Of course it does not. It prints `1` as expected. What you got wrong is this line:

```
echo  $save = "temp/". strtolower($code) .".jpeg";
```

it should be:

```
$save = "temp/". strtolower($code) .".jpeg"; 
echo $save;
```

instead.

Comment: Sure it is. But you know the difference or not?